# Обработка исключений

Tags: delphi

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  a,b,c,x1,x2,d: real;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
a:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
b:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text) ;
c:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text) ;
 d:=sqr(b)-4*a*c;
 if d>0 then
        begin
        try
          x1:=(-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
          x2:=(-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
          except
          on EzeroDivide do MessageDLG('Ділення на 0!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
          end;
          ShowMessage('x1='+FloatToStr(x1)+',x2='+FloatToStr(x2));
          end
 else  if  d=0 then
        begin
        try
        x1:=(-b)/(2*a); //здесь вылетает ошибка Invalid floating point operation

except
          on EzeroDivide do MessageDLG('Ділення на 0!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
          end;
        ShowMessage('x='+FloatToStr(x1));
        end
 else  if d<0 then
        begin
        try
        x1:=(-b+sqrt(abs(d)))/(2*a);
        x2:=(-b-sqrt(abs(d)))/(2*a);
        except
        on EzeroDivide do MessageDLG('Ділення на 0!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
          end;
       ShowMessage('x1='+FloatToStr(x1)+',x2='+FloatToStr(x2));
        end

end;
end.
```

Так вот, подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так и как с этим бороться?

Comment: ошибка выскакивает именно тогда,когда в переменную (а) ложится ноль!
в иных случаях программа работает корректно. try ведь должен это обработать верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**

**...**

**Except**

Не работают под IDE то есть, если открыта Delphi то будет вылетать ошибка, а возьмите запустите программу не из Delphi и вылетать ошибка не будет.

Comment: не помогло..

Comment: В смысле не помогло?

Comment: ошибка осталась..может я не так понял "а возьмите запустите программу не из Delphi и вылетать ошибка не будет."
запустил просто экзешник .если я не так понял,тогда вопрос: как это не работают если это задание по учебной программе?
и дополню что использую Delphi 7

Comment: Да взял ваш пример, откомпилировал в delphi7, действительно при вводе 0 в Edit1 вылетает. Сейчас копаюсь.

Comment: огромное спасибо..интересно ведь)
уже даже не задания ради...

Comment: Ну я переписал кусок так

    if  d=0 then
        begin
       if a<>0 then x1:=(-b)/(2*a) else MessageDLG('деление на       0!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
                ShowMessage('x='+FloatToStr(x1));
        end 

А ошибка получается из за деления на 0 только вот почему его не обрабатывает TRY не понятно

Я подозреваю что у Вас операционка Windows7

В ней действительно связка try ... except на математические операции не срабатывает Вот статья у человек аналогичная проблема

Comment: нет не 7ка..,у меня ХР!  спасибо..
правда ваш код не спасает так как я должен показать обработку ситуации деления на ноль именно через try..
однако спасибо за уделённое время!

Comment: В общем Ваша ошибка в том что
a b c равны
и если а=0 и b=0 то получается что (-0)\(2*0)=0\0 а вот 0 деленный на 0 это бесконечность :)
И поэтому не ошибка связанная с деление на ноль а ошибка с тем что число слишком велико.
Достаточно поставить вместо b число отличное от 0 и ловушка срабатывает с радостью с сообщением что происходит деление на ноль.
Так что можете потрепать мозг преподу заставив его отловить ошибку деления на ноль :) если оба аргумента 0

Comment: Что примечательно, в Delphi 2010 можно делить 0 на 0 безо всякого вреда.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
try
  x1:=(-b)/(2*a); //здесь вылетает ошибка Invalid floating point operation
except
  MessageDLG('Ділення на 0!',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;
  ShowMessage('x='+FloatToStr(x1));
...
```